# Manual autodiscover implementation failing. Why?

Tags: xml, email, curl, outlook, autodiscovery

I am managing a mail server, and would like to have my Outlook users be able to automatically set up their mail server information. Normally this is done with an autodiscover file. Here's how I understand it works with `mymaildomain.com` as an example (not the actual domain):

- Host a file at `mymaildomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` (https) with the correct information
- User enters `foobar@mymaildomain.com` and their correct password
- Outlook then tries to fetch the autodiscover XML from one of the following URLs:

  - https://mymaildomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
  - https://autodiscover.mymaildomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
- Outlook uses the information in that file to populate the correct fields like IMAP, POP, and SMTP server names, ports, etc.

I've got the file hosted (pasted below) and when I open a browser or use curl to `GET` or `POST` the URL, I get `HTTP/200` and the XML is returned properly. When I try it in Outlook for Mac 15.17.1, it doesn't work. When I use the Remote Connectivity Analyzer, it gives me the following error:

```
The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to retrieve an XML Autodiscover response from URL 
https://mymaildomain.com:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml for user 
testlogin@mymaildomain.com.

    The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer failed to obtain an Autodiscover XML response.

Additional Details

An HTTP 500 response was returned from Unknown.
HTTP Response Headers:
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2524
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 22:15:53 GMT
Server: ""
Elapsed Time: 582 ms.
```

What's baffling is that any other method I use to request the autodiscover.xml file, I'm able to get it.  So why can't Outlook or the Remote Connectivity Analyzer fetch it properly? XML file below.

Thanks

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
<Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
<Account>
<AccountType>email</AccountType>
<Action>settings</Action>
<Protocol>
<Type>IMAP</Type>
<Server>imap.mymaildomain.com</Server>
<Port>993</Port>
<DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
</Protocol>
<Protocol>
<Type>POP3</Type>
<Server>pop.mymaildomain.com</Server>
<Port>995</Port>
<DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
</Protocol>
<Protocol>
<Type>SMTP</Type>
<Server>smtp.mymaildomain.com</Server>
<Port>465</Port>
<DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
<UsePOPAuth>on</UsePOPAuth>
<SMTPLast>on</SMTPLast>
</Protocol>
</Account>
</Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

Comment: Do you see anything on the server logs for the 500 error?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server logs directly. I could ask my client, but it might be a while before they can get it.